# PHP SQL Server injections

Tags: php, sql-server, escaping

Is this the way to prevent (all) Microsoft SQL Server injections if you want to use ODBC?

```
public function mssql_escape($str)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()):
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    endif;

    return str_replace("'", "''", $str);
}
```

Comment: several other posts out there on this topic, but short answer is no, there are far better ways to deal with sql injection.

Comment: **NO** - use **parametrized queries** - that's the only viable way to go

Comment: What @marc_s said... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php